# Split Data Frame for passing to sprintf in R

Tags: r, dataframe, printf, lapply

I have a sprintf format string that I'm trying to parse a dataframe in R through. I built this code to do it, but it is nothing if not ugly. What's a better way to do this?

```
writeData<-function(DataSet,FirstLine,FmtString,fName){
    correctLine<-function (MyLine,FmtString){
        do.call(sprintf,c(FmtString,MyLine))
    }
    #why the ugly split code? Because otherwise it casts my nice data frame as characters which confuses sprintf.
    outLines=lapply(split(DataSet,1:NROW(DataSet)),function (x){correctLine(x,FmtString)})
    writeLines(unlist(outLines),fName)
    return(0)
}
```

Here's an example:

```
z=data.frame(d1=c("A","B","C"),d2=c(1,2,3),d3=c("D","E","F"),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
fmt="%s %0.3f %s"
writeData(z,"",fmt,"~/sample.txt")
```

Contrast:

```
correctLine<-function (MyLine,FmtString){do.call(sprintf,c(FmtString,MyLine))}
apply(z,1,function(x) {correctLine(x,fmt)}) #Errors out, wants a list
correctLine<-function (MyLine,FmtString){do.call(sprintf,as.list(c(FmtString,MyLine)))}
apply(z,1,function(x) {correctLine(x,fmt)}) # - still unhappy, now we have a character array. This is the problem.
```

Comment: a `dput` of part of the actual data frame would be helpful

Comment: Are you trying to apply the formatting to each row? You're better off doing a column-wise transformation. In R it's almost always better to work with entire columns at a time. Also, it's not helpful to ask "is there a better way to do this"; it's better to describe what you're trying to accomplish. Otherwise we have to try to reverse engineer your code to figure out what you're trying to accomplish. Providing sample input is good, but then you should also tell us what the desired output is.

Comment: Just curious, why `return(0)`?  R isn't C, it doesn't seem necessary there.  Or do you actually want it to return the number zero?

Comment: Force of habit. Definitely not useful here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to do correctly, you really only need to call `sprintf` once with all your columns to do the formatting. For example

```
writeData <- function(DataSet,FirstLine, FmtString,fName){
    outlines <- do.call("sprintf", c(FmtString, DataSet))
    writeLines(outLines,fName)
    return(0)
}
```

Most functions in R are meant to work with vectors of data so just pass in the entire column at a time rather than iterating over the rows.

Comment: You get the green check. Works great. Just because sprintf is a function from C doesn't mean I have to treat it like I would in C.