# Format data frame data with sprintf

Tags: r

After reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28058501/split-data-frame-for-passing-to-sprintf-in-r), I tried to do the same with my data frame:

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4)
y <- c(5,6,7,8)
my.df <- data.frame(x, y)
do.call("sprintf", c("%14.7E", my.df))
```

But this only works for the first column:

```
[1] " 1.0000000E+00" " 2.0000000E+00" " 3.0000000E+00" " 4.0000000E+00"
```

What I want is this:

```
 1.0000000E+00 5.0000000E+00
 2.0000000E+00 6.0000000E+00
 3.0000000E+00 7.0000000E+00
 4.0000000E+00 8.0000000E+00
```

So I can write it to a file that will be read by a fortran code.

Comment: Using `do.call` applies to each row i.e. `do.call(sprintf, c(my.df, fmt = "%d.%d"))`

Comment: You may want to also look at `format.data.frame`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We need to loop through the columns and individually apply `sprintf`

```
my.df[] <- lapply(my.df, sprintf, fmt = "%14.7E")
my.df
#              x              y
#1  1.0000000E+00  5.0000000E+00
#2  2.0000000E+00  6.0000000E+00
#3  3.0000000E+00  7.0000000E+00
#4  4.0000000E+00  8.0000000E+00
```

Comment: is this `my.df[]` like a shortcut for `as.data.frame`? Or is there something different happening under the hood. Haven't seen this before. Nice solution

Comment: @drmariod  thanks. It is just to keep the structure of the original data.frame.  The `lapply` output is a `list` strcture,